# Need configurations for integrating latest version of Bing search api in Ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bing-api, bing-search

Getting error:

> Geocoding API error: 401 Unauthorized
>       Invalid Bing API key.

After putting Bing search api primary key in geokit_config.rb and geocoder.rb in Ruby on rails application. Do I need any other configurations for integrate Bing search api (part of Microsoft cognitive search) in Ruby on rails application?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Improved formatting.